# What sequences do we need to prove continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

The continuity of a real function $f$ at the point $x_0$ can be characterized with sequences as

$$x_n \to x_0 \implies f(x_n) \to f(x_0) \space \space \forall (x_n)$$

But can we restrict the set of considered sequences to be the ones satisfying

$$ \frac{c}{2^{n+1}} \leq |x_{n+1} - x_n| \leq \frac{C}{2^{n+1}} $$

for some positive constants $c$ and $C$?

If any sequence converging to $x_0$ can be sparsened and/or filled to satisfy this condition, then it works. But is this true?

Comment: I think if $C > 2c > 0$, you can achieve by sparsening to achieve the upper bound on $|x_{n+1} - x_n|$ and then interleaving with little jumps to achieve the lower bound. I don't claim to have worked out all the details. Out of interest, why do you want this?

Comment: @RobArthan I thought of using the Stolz-Cesàro theorem to show that $\frac{f(x)}{x} \to 0$ when we have $\frac{f(x)-f(x/2)}{x} \to 0$ and $f(x) \to 0$, as $x \to 0$. So I would like to use the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$. Now that by itself won't show the limit so I thought of using all the sequences that have approx same difference. But I realise that won't probably help since we have no additional information on $f$. Well, I decided to ask the general question anyhow. The problem is Putnam A5, 1954.